# Redesign the Titlebar

Tags: windows-os, title

I was wondering,

### is it a good idea to redesign the Titlebar of desktop applications?

What I mean with that is to get rid of the standard Titlebar of boring Windows and redesign the Titlebar together with these "Close, Maximize, Minimize,..." actions in a nice design.

What I can think of, is that some users may be confused and don't find some standard actions, on the other hand, if you implement it in a good fashion, your application stand out from others and may let the user have a really comfortable workflow.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's not **really** clear what you're asking exactly. Which is why some people are voting to close your question. Try to edit your question to make it very clear what it is exactly that you're asking.

Comment: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer depends on how different your titlebar will be from the 'standard'.

Usually this would cause confusion, as in most cases, it will differ from the OS standard unless you're using it uniformly over a custom OS like some kind of Linux system(?).

I would ask **why** are you redesigning the Titlebar? If it's just because you can then I would say it's invariably a bad idea.